# None of the selectors i tried are working

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

i want to select "projects" from a side menu but it's not working
i tried the selector from cypress first and then other selectors but none of them are working i get an error of "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: never found"
that's the element :

```
<li class="ant-menu-item menu-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-menu-id="rc-menu-uuid-17523-1-/projects"
    style="padding-left: 24px">
    <span role="img" aria-label="project" class="anticon anticon-project ant-menu-item-icon"><svg
            viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" data-icon="project" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <path
                d="M280 752h80c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V280c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8h-80c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v464c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8zm192-280h80c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V280c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8h-80c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v184c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8zm192 72h80c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V280c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8h-80c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v256c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8zm216-432H144c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32v736c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32h736c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32V144c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32zm-40 728H184V184h656v656z">
            </path>
        </svg></span><span class="ant-menu-title-content">Projects</span>
</li>
```

my selectors were:
`

```
cy.get(
  '[data-menu-id="rc-menu-uuid-25600-1-/projects"] > .ant-menu-title-content'
).click()
cy.get('[data-menu-id="rc-menu-uuid-37316-1-/projects"]')
cy.contains('Projects').click()
cy.xpath('//*[@id="master"]/section/aside/div/ul/li[5]').click()
```

`

Comment: well `rc-menu-uuid-25600-1-` does not exist in the HTML you gave us. The html is `data-menu-id="rc-menu-uuid-17523-1-/projects"` so it an oversight you pasted the wrong html?

Comment: its the right html

Comment: So how does `rc-menu-uuid-25600-1-` match `rc-menu-uuid-17523-1-`??? Unsure how you are expecting that selector to match when the uuid is different....

Comment: i did try cy.get('[data-menu-id="rc-menu-uuid-17523-1-/projects"]').click() and it didn't work also

Comment: and when i put rc-menu-uuid-17523-1-/projects in cypress it says no matches

Comment: but why cy.contains('Projects') doesnot work?